# where to add code of instantiating an instance from Vue in compositional API

Tags: vue.js

as i am following this tutorial [here](https://codingexplained.com/coding/front-end/vue-js/asynchronous-update-queue)

i wanted to run the following code:

```
<div id="app">
{{ message }}
</div>

var vm = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        message: 'Hello!'
    }
});
```

i created a new project but i do not know where to add the above mentioned code so i can run it.

i create the new project using "vue create xx" command

**project App.vue**:

```
<template>
  <img alt="Vue logo" src="./assets/logo.png">
  <HelloWorld msg="Welcome to Your Vue.js App"/>

    <div id="app">
        {{ message }}
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import HelloWorld from './components/HelloWorld.vue'

export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
    HelloWorld
  }

  var vm = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        message: 'Hello!'
    }
});
}
</script>
```

please let me know how and where to add the code that instantiate an object of Vue so i can complete the tutorial

**my attempts**:

```
<script setup>
    import { Vue } from 'vue'

    var vm = new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data: {
            message: 'Hello!'
        }
    });

console.log("vm:",vm);

</script>
```

**error generated**

```
error  Object declaration on 'data' property is deprecated. Using 
function declaration instead  vue/no-deprecated-data-object-declaration
```

Comment: Please provide more info how exactly you have created a new project. Did you use the vue-cli for that?

Comment: @meridbt yes, i create the new project using "vue create xx" command

Comment: I'd suggest to just not follow old tutorials if you need up-to-date info. That it uses data object and not data function suggests that it's really old, since this has already been a problem long before composition api. It's 6 y.o.

Answer (score 0):

When creating a project with cli, an template is being initialized.
Find `<div id="app>` in your *index.html*. This is the entry point where Vue app is being mounted to. Don't place any vue elements inside it.

Vue application created in *main.ts* (if you've chosen TypeScript):

```
// main.ts
import { createApp } from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";

const app = createApp(App);

app.mount("#app");
```

As you see, the app uses *App.vue* as a root component of the application. So, you can place your logic there. Check below simple example in composition-api syntax

```html
// App.vue
<template>
  <span>{{ message }} </span>
</template>


<script setup lang="ts">
  import { ref, onMounted } from 'vue';

  const messagge = ref('');

  onMounted(() => {
    message.value = 'Hello World';
  }
</script>
```

[Reference](https://vuejs.org/guide/extras/composition-api-faq.html#what-is-composition-api)